# how to dereference interfaces joined with OR in typescript

Tags: typescript

I need to dereference an interface which is joined to another interface by OR in typescript

Below is my equivalent code

```
interface A {
  a: Array<B>;
}

interface A2 {
  a: C;
}

interface B {
  b: { bb: string; };
}

interface C {
  c: { d: string; };
}

interface D {
  abc: A | A2;
}

type E = D["abc"]["a"]["c"];
```

I get an error at `["c"]` saying `property c does not exist on type...`

how do I go down `interface A2` and not `A` after `D["abc"]["a"]`

Comment: What are you actually trying to _achieve_ here? You could use e.g. [`Exclude`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers) but at that point you have to already know what the relevant types are. This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @jonrsharpe I could use Exclude if the keys in A and A2 were both not named "a", my problem is to choose the "a"  from A2 and not A

Comment: You're thinking of `Omit`, `Exclude<D["abc"], A>` would be `A2`, so `Exclude<D["abc"], A>["a"]["c"]` would be fine.

Comment: @jonrsharpe actually I cannot directly refer to `A` so `Exclude<D["abc"], A>` is not possible, otherwise I would directly do `type E = C["c"];`

Comment: As I said, _"at that point you have to already know what the relevant types are"_ (and might as well just _use `A2`_ instead. It's not clear how you're expecting TypeScript to know what you mean, or the underlying problem that led you to try this.

Comment: @jonrsharpe the problem I am trying to solve is this- I am generating types from openApi spec using openapi-typescript, I am reexporting the api response types from a index file which references the types using urls as keys and doesn't directly refer the schema names as they can change, urls won't. refering `A` directly would mean refering the schema name directly

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include relevant context.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to whatever `A` or `A2` is, then the simplest thing you can do is to extract all members that have a property `c`:

```
type E = Extract<D["abc"]["a"], { c: any }>["c"];
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `type E = Extract<D["abc"]["a"], "c">;`? what is `{ c: any }` doing?

Comment: @RahulYadav See the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) on `Extract<T, U>`. It filters for members of T that are assignable to U.